# www-data user cannot access the files created by dumpcap application in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2

I am trying to access a file created by dumpcap application in ubuntu via Apache server. But it shows an error that **'Permission denied'**.

After checking I found that the files are creating by the following permission mode **'rw-------'**.

I tried the below ways, but could not solve the issue.

**1.**  Set directory in dumpcap in which www-data user has access, but still all files are creating with this permission **'rw-------'**.

**2.**  Set all permissions to its parent directory recursively by the following command **chmod -R 777 directory**, but files creating in it are with the older permission .

Please can anyone suggest a way to get a solution for this?

Comment: Are you running `dumpcap` command yourself manually or is it automated?

Comment: It is running as a subprocess from python script.

Comment: well, you could probably run that python script as www-data user.

Comment: We came across this idea but don't know how to run the script as www-data user.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated in comments, that you have python script, that runs `dumpcap` command. Try running that python script as www-data user, like so:

```
sudo -u www-data [command/script to run]
```

Comment: I tried using **"sudo -u www-data dumpcap -D"** but got an error that 'sudo: unable to execute/usr/bin/dumpcap: Permission denied'.

Comment: Maybe you need to `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/dumpcap` and try running your command again.

Comment: It is working now. I had to give permission for interfaces also. I run the following command also **sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE+eip /usr/bin/dumpcap**. Thank you Azamat.